# Create list of Safari bookmarks

Tags: iphone, safari, bookmarks

I want to create a list of my Safari bookmarks (folder, webpage title, and URL) to put into Numbers or a database app. This will help me find duplicates, tell me where a certain bookmark is, and keep from saving bookmarks again and again.

Comment: You can export the bookmarks within Safari: File - Export Bookmarks.

Comment: to add to @Scot : this exports an HTML file that can be opened with Excel or a text editor where the data can be manipulated.  Is this the type of thing you are looking to do?

Answer (score 1):

**Safari** Bookmarks can be exported as an HTML file.  This file can be opened with any text editor and reviewed or even cleaned up with a little HTML know-how.  Then it can be reimported after clean up.  Recommend cleaning up a copy of the original in case you need to revert.

---

**To export:**

- From the *Menu*: File > Export Bookmarks...
- Choose a location to save the HTML file.
- Open in a text editor.  (Drag the file to the text editor's application icon or <kbd>option</kbd>+click and choose *Open with*
- Examine the file and make changes.
- Reimport using File > Import From > Bookmarks HTML File…

Alternatively, if one just wants to examine in a spreadsheet, Excel for Mac will open HTML files.  Even though the result is easier to read, the data is harder to manipulate unless you understand Hyperlinks.